# Stata - summary detail specifics (skewness and Std Dev) by id and date range

Tags: stata, date-range, summary, standard-deviation, skew

I have a panel data set with an id, date, and multiple variables. I'm trying to get the skewness and std dev of "var1" listed by id for a certain date range. I know those items are in the summary detail for "var1", but can't seem to find a way to get it listed by id for my specified date range.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post some code so we can see what you've done so far.

Comment: @TrevorBrooks - beyond setting the data up as a panel (using xtset command), I don't have code to show. I'm just using this dataset to generate the skewness and std dev of a couple variables (by id for a specific date range) so I can import those into my other main data by id. After about 10 hours of failed stata commands and google searches, I finally figured it was time to admit defeat and ask.

Comment: Using the same example dataset as William Lisowski below, you may also try: `statsby r(skewness) r(sd), by(id) clear: summarize weight if inrange(week,3,8), detail`. See [statsby](https://www.stata.com/help.cgi?statsby) in Stata help. It will destroy the current dataset, but there are ways to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that may start you on your path.

```
. webuse pig
(Longitudinal analysis of pig weights)

. xtset id week
       panel variable:  id (strongly balanced)
        time variable:  week, 1 to 9
                delta:  1 unit

. bysort id: egen sk = skew(weight) if inrange(week,3,8)
(144 missing values generated)

. list if id==1, clean

       id   week   weight         sk  
  1.    1      1       24          .  
  2.    1      2       32          .  
  3.    1      3       39   .0709604  
  4.    1      4     42.5   .0709604  
  5.    1      5       48   .0709604  
  6.    1      6     54.5   .0709604  
  7.    1      7       61   .0709604  
  8.    1      8       65   .0709604  
  9.    1      9       72          .
```